# El Capitan upgrade white screen

Tags: hard-drive, mac, backup

I recently upgraded my late 2007 iMac to el capitan.
The computer was very sluggish for a couple of weeks keep freezing on us.
And than after the last update it died completely, white screen with the apple stuck at 75% flicker and freeze.
I looked on line and did all that was suggested, reset PRAM, single user(shft S), disk utility-multiple times did a first aid, reinstall OS from disk util via internet to no avail. nothing worked, 
I was able to backup on external drive the HD internal drive as .IMG
I was told this is a hardware issue and I either lost the hard drive or the graphics card. I than found an old time machine drive, I plugged it in and there was a backup from 2013, I installed the old back-up and the computer came to live with a 10.6.8 OS, but all functioning very well.
I thought now I can install the backup from yesterday back, I re-installed el-capitan so I'll have a recovery again, the computer stuck on same white screen with the apple at 75%.
I tried installing the backup and same thing.
Obviously my computer doesn't like el-capitan, how can I install Yosemite back? I have no backups or time machines with it.
and also, how can I extract all my data from the resent backup?

Thank you in advance!